# Creating DLL in C# tobe used by Thired party application at part of their application

Tags: c#-4.0

I have created one C# Dll with Functions with parameters for showing different forms

used following code to show the form

```
Form1 SIForm = new Form1(dt);
SIForm.Show();
```

the code is working fine and it's displaying the form1 as separate form

but wanted to know is there any way to show the form as part of the application, e.g. if form is minimized then that application also get minimized and if they minimize the application then form also get minimized

if they close the form then they can continue working with their application

Comment: Just hook to the events as you usually would, if it's a regular winforms form.

Comment: how to do the same ?

Comment: The most correct answer is "no".  Consider the kind of windowing model you see back in Visual Studio, docking layout libraries are plentiful.  I couldn't recommend MDI.  Or keep it simple and create a UserControl instead.

Comment: its done thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

i changed the code from

```
Form1 SIForm = new Form1(dt);
SIForm.Show();
```

to

```
Form1 SIForm = new Form1(dt);
SIForm.ShowDialog();
```